# If I resize the browser window by 10 px how do i resize the logo on the header by 1 pixel for example?

Tags: css, responsive-design, image-resizing

I have a fixed header this header change the height and the image logo when i scroll but when i resize the window i want the image to keep is ratio but to get smaller as I shrink the browser the logo only shrinks when the limit of the browser gets near the image but i want the image to get smaller as i resize the browser.

how can i do that?

```html
<div id="logo"><a href="#.html"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="images/logo.png" alt=""/></a></div>
```

i have already try this

```css
#logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Comment: You could use JavaScript to grab the sizes, and increase the logo by a percentage.  So, if the window just enlarged by 10px wide, you have Javascript resize the logo 10% of that.  Just as an example.

Comment: yeah that's great! can you send me an example... i'm not very 
comfortable with javascript xDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be approached as straightforward as one might think at first because there would have to be a reference point at what screen size the logo has the same width as the screen. Any dimensions it's currently displayed on would have to relate to this point for the resizing to make sense as a whole (and to start with). That said, I've taken 2560 pixels as the largest size here - below that the logo will be 10% smaller than the difference between the momentary size and the reference point :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNLQKX

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).on('load resize', function() {

    var maxsize = 2560;
    var screenwidth = $(this).width();
    var factor = screenwidth-(maxsize-screenwidth)*0.1;
    if (factor > 2560) factor = 2560; // same could be done for minimum size

    $('#logo img').css('width', factor)
  });
});
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could scribble something together that was useful. I chose to use jQuery here which is *extended* JavaScript - it makes the code very compact. But keep it mind that it would need a link to the library when you want to place it on your web page. Cheers.

Comment: this only works if the width of the logo image is filling the entire page?

Comment: You can give it any size you like of course by tweaking the value for factor. This will only ever make it half the screen size for example : `factor = 0.5*(screenwidth-(maxsize-screenwidth)*0.1)`. Plus you could position it anywhere, I just left it centered for demonstrative purpose.